# Share a folder to a specific computer without login

Tags: windows-7, encryption, disk-encryption

is there a way to Share a folder to a specific computer on the network without login? meaning the pc that is sharing the folder has no account authenication

Answer (score 0):

The **Public folders** are a convenient way to share files on your computer.The Public folders are located in the **C:\Users\Public** folder, and also included in libraries by default.

**steps** :

- go to the C:\Users\Public folder.
- Paste the folder there.
- Right click on folder in the Public folder, click on **Share with and Advanced sharing settings**.
- change to **public** profile
- Select radio button that says **Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and    write files in the Public folders**.
- Save Changes.exit.

Now go to any other system in your home group , press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for **run** , then type \\ipadressofhost\ bam , there comes your shared folder.